# How to print receipt with ethernet POS printer with printer name in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer, pos

I am trying to print receipts for POS printer that is not accessible with Wifi nor Bluetooth. It can only be connected with USB or network cable (now, connecting with Ethernet). I found examples to print POS printer are connecting with IP address. There are more than one printer connected to the server. How can I make Flutter app to print receipt to specific printer that is Ethernet connected server?

Answer (score 0):

I can print simple receipts using the esc_pos_printer plugin, but only simple text works for me. I can't change font size, make columns etc...
https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer

You have to specify your local printer ip and use PORT 9100. The printer IP is 192.168.0.'something'.

I used another app from App Store called Retail POS to connect my printer via Ethernet and see the IP.

Hope this helps somewhat.

If you find a solution where you can print more than just simple lines of text let me know!